# Recommending Deletion not showing up in user's reviews

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, low-quality-posts, recent-activity

#### When reviewing Low Quality posts and recommending deletion:

[image]

---

#### They don't show up in the user's reviews actions:

[image]

---

#### Nor are they showing up under any other actions:

[image]

---

#### They're not showing up in votes cast either:

[image]

---

1. Why is this?
2. Is this a bug?
3. Can we get them to count?

I ask, as people frequently, use their stats when running for moderator elections or room owner positions on the sites.

Comment: Delete and RecommendDelete result types are intentionally *supposed* to be hidden altogether from that list, presumably because deleted posts don't show up there anyways, thus if your action is successful, it will get removed. However, the current behavior is bugged (maybe IDs got changed) and it actually hides RecommendDelete and RecommendClose result types. If that bug didn't exist, the idea is that we shouldn't show result types where the only ones you'll actually see are your failed attempts (you'd only see RecommendDelete if it didn't get deleted).

Comment: @animuson I can see my delete votes. So shouldn't I be able to see the RecommendDelete actions?

Comment: There's currently a bug where it's hiding RecommendClose actions instead of Delete actions. You're not supposed to see Delete actions.

Comment: @animuson but I can see my own delete votes

Comment: You mean the votes tab? That's a completely different function. You see that because a) you have enough reputation and b) only you see your own votes. Your review activity is public to any person who views your profile, and we don't show deleted content there ever.

Comment: If you go to the review queue's history tab, select "my reviews" bottom right, then you get those. eg: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?userId=3956566 (not public admittedly but they're there...)

Comment: @animuson something you didn't address, is that it's a review action which does not appear to be counted. So you say it is counted, just not displayed in the activity due to the bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep thanks

Comment: @JonClements thanks for that tip! I'm also trying to get the reviews counted as reviews.

Comment: @animuson ah I see. Do the recommencdeletion reviews count towards the review count? IIRC it doesn't, last time I checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major component of the review activity tab on your profile that you *must* understand is that **deleted posts are never shown there**. No matter what queue the review happened in, if the parent post ends up being deleted, the review task will also disappear from your list shortly after. In that sense, you should not consider the number of reviews in that tab to be in any way accurate, nor should you think that it is an exhaustive list of all your review activity. It's not.

Having said that, there's something else to display about showing Delete-type actions in a list where those successful attempts to delete end up being hidden anyways. Essentially, we have a queue wherein your delete actions resulting in the post actually being deleted always cause the post to be hidden from your history. We then end up with users whose history only composes of Delete-type actions which were *unsuccessful*, which looks kind of crappy. No one wants a history filled with only non-success. So Delete and Recommend Delete actions are hidden from that list altogether.

At least, they're *supposed* to be. Whether the ReviewTaskTypeIds changed or the wrong ones were used in the first place, the query that fetches that list *actually* excludes Recommend Delete and Recommend Close results, incorrectly.

As far as the votes tab where you can see full-out delete votes you've cast - that's an entirely separate beast most easily distinguished by audience. The audience of the votes tab is you and you alone. You can see all of your delete votes because only you can see that list and in order to delete a post you have to have access to see the deleted post anyways, so it's not a big problem. (Also note that Recommend Delete is not an *actual* vote, just a review task result. Deleting from that queue adds *both* a review task result and an actual delete vote.) But your review history is a public list, visible to everyone, and thus cannot have deleted posts contained within it. So we end up with the dilemma described above.

Will any of this ever change? I mean, I hope the bug part of it gets fixed. But the rest, probably not.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug; "Recommend Deletion" actions are hidden but "Delete" ones are not: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328789/why-do-delete-reviews-show-up-in-users-profiles-but-not-recommend-deletion

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog My answer here explicitly addresses what the problem is. Paragraph 3.

Comment: No, the issue is not related to the "votes" tab, but to the "actions" tab, and when looking at others' user profiles as well. Per the screenshots in the question I linked, "Delete" review actions are shown to other users while "Recommend Deletion" actions are not.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog You seem to have read paragraph 4 instead of 3.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did read the wrong paragraph. So you mean to say that the query that is supposed to exclude "Recommend Deletion" and "Delete" reviews, excludes "Recommend Deletion" and "Recommend Close" reviews instead?