# Why do "Delete" reviews show up in user's profiles but not "Recommend Deletion" reviews?

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

You can view a user's review history by going to the *Activity -> All Actions -> Reviews* section of their profile. I've come across one strange behavior: Delete reviews in Low Quality Posts *do* show up if the post is not currently deleted, but Recommend Deletion reviews do *not* show up, regardless of whether the post is currently deleted or not.

I've seen this in a user's profile (anonymized user ID and number of reviews for privacy reasons):

[image]

However, [the most recent review I performed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/64984) was a Recommend Deletion review, but it doesn't show up in [my review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/405220/pikachu-the-watermelon-wizard?tab=activity):

[image]

I've seen countless examples on many different sites and all of them had this same behavior.

I understand why Recommend Deletion reviews would be hidden, but why not Delete reviews as well? What's the reason for this?

*Not a duplicate of [Recommending Deletion not showing up in user's reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303499/recommending-deletion-not-showing-up-in-users-reviews) because this is asking about why only Delete reviews show up in user profiles and Recommend Deletions don't, and that's just about why Recommend Deletion reviews do not show up.*

Comment: This seems like a bug to me, since the answer to the post you linked says that "Delete" reviews are indeed hidden.

Comment: And indeed, this is a bug. Per the answer, the query that excludes certain things excludes "Recommend Close" actions instead of "Delete" actions.